# How can I get the functionality of svn:externals in a read-only fashion?

Tags: svn

svn:externals can be great for sucking in central libraries or IP into a project, so that they can be kept in one location accessible for all.

But if I'm asking people to external tags of common IP (so it doesn't change on them) it opens the possibility of them inadvertently committing changes to the tag.

How can I make svn:externals read-only?  It's acceptable if there is some extra argument or some way of making the external that we can add to the procedure for everyone to follow.

Comment: I understand what people are saying about how this shouldn't be needed.  You don't *need* a parking brake either, but it's a good idea to use one.  It would be nice if this was possible without modifying apache, which isn't available to most users without getting admin involved.

Comment: Note that the command line interface does not recurse into externals when committing by default. Changes in externals are grayed-out in the Tortoise GUI when invoking commit from the parent working directory. This makes accidental commits to the external project less likely.

Answer (score 5):

Using svn repository hooks to avoid commting into special dirs e.g. tags

If you´re using the ttb (trunk, tags, branches)  naming convention and the code for read-only svn:external access resides in  tags-directories, you can use the pre-commit hook to avoid commiting into those directories.

Here´re are the details:
[SVN pre-commit hook for avoiding changes to tags subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464384/svn-pre-commit-hook-for-avoiding-changes-to-tags-subdirectories)

Comment: Seems like the best way to accomplish what the OP wants.

Answer (score 3):

Make the external repositories read-only to everyone except their maintainers.

Comment: And what if you don't want the maintainers committed via the external, but do need to maintain the code?

Comment: it may be that most devs are maintainers on both locations

Answer (score 1):

Actually, TortoiseSVN detects you are trying to commit to a tag through the commit hook, and warns the user of this, which basically satisfies my requirement for a speed bump.  So we're already good.

Answer (score 1):

> Make the external repositories read-only to everyone except their maintainers.

I totally agree to [J. John](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245149/how-can-i-get-the-functionality-of-svnexternals-in-a-read-only-fashion/245166#245166)'s answer above. Creating a pre-commit hook is overkill. svn:externals (is simply a reference to an external repository, hence the name) and so is still on a separate repository(you can verify that by going to the checked-out external and do 'svn info|grep URL') so just put the necessary permission in that external repo. Something like:

```
[external_repo]
@maintainer = rw
@others = r
```

And from repo(let's call this repoA) where this is defined as "external"(let's call the external repo as repoB), you don't need to do anything. When someone(other than the person who is part of @maintainers) tries to commit to the external repo through the code he/she checked-out from repoA, commit will be directed to the external repoB and hence, the permission you set something like above on that repo will kick-in and block the commit.

Hope this help clear things.

Ismael Casimpan :)

Comment: what if most devs are a maintainers on both locations?