# Subversion: Write protection for tagged directories

Tags: svn, configuration-management, version-control, rcs

i am using subversion as RCS. Always when a new version of my project is finised i create a tag of it (copy of the trunk).
Does anybody know how i can protect this tagged directory from being accidentally modified?

At the moment as a workaround i lock all files. But this sill means that the user with the lock can edit the files.

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a pre-commit hook to prevent users from writing to a `tags` directory after it has been created.

See this related SO question for examples:
[SVN pre-commit hook for avoiding changes to tags subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464384/svn-pre-commit-hook-for-avoiding-changes-to-tags-subdirectories)

Comment: Pre-commit hooks are scripts that can do more complex things, like only allow changes in the tags directories by certain users.

Comment: If a pre-commit hook is the official way i will set the SVN attribute "svn:needs-lock" on all files instead.

Comment: Don't do setting the property on all files...this is against the idea of SVN. The answer given about path-based-authorization is the correct way.

Answer (score 2):

You can give read only permission on the tag directories using [path-based authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html).

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you can't create new `tags`.  If certain users are granted write permission, there is always a chance of mistakenly modifying files within a tag.

Comment: You can set in read only the tags after creating them, leaving the usual /tags subdirectory writeable: es: /myproject/tags is writeable, while /myproject/tags/my-first-tag is set to readonly after the tag creation.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `svn:needs-lock` attribute for all files in the tag, all files will be checked out as read-only unless the user explicitly acquires a lock.  This will (in most cases) prevent files being changed.  It does not prevent anyone from changing the read-only flag or acquiring a lock, but it reduce the chances of accidental modification.

Subversion itself cannot apply the `svn:needs-lock` attribute to a folder, but in the TortoiseSVN client (Windows) for example if you attempt to do so, it applies the property to all files in the folder and sub-folders instead.  It won't let you do this from the TortioseSVN repo-browser, so you must check-out a working copy of the tag, modify the properties, and then check in the property changes.  Other clients may vary; if you are using the native subversion command line client, a suitable shell script or similar may be necessary to iterate through files and sub-folders to apply the attribute in bulk.  TortoiseSVN does at least warn you if you attempt to change anything in a `Tags` folder - but that is only a convention, not an enforcement.

The `svn:needs-lock` solution is somewhat weak and easily circumvented and does not prevent new files being *added* to a tag folder; a stronger alternative is to create a dummy user, and acquire a lock for the entire tag in that users name.  This will prevent "real" users from being able to check-in, and working-copy checkouts will have their read-only attribute set just like with `svn:needs-lock` - the difference is that they will not be able to acquire a lock, and changing the working copy read-only attribute will not allow check-in either.

Comment: I know the question is old, but I was looking for a solution to exactly this and found this question.  This answer describes what I am currently intending to do as there seems to be no direct support for this.