# Users validation in SVN pre-commit hook

Tags: svn, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

Found one of the useful SVN pre-commit hook in [SVN pre-commit hook for avoiding changes to tags subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464384/svn-pre-commit-hook-for-avoiding-changes-to-tags-subdirectories/3550191#3550191) by mcdon.

I want to add the validation check on the user before committing. Can I do something like below?

```
@echo off
REM  user1, user2, user3 are example
set VALID_USERS=user1,user2,user3

set SVNROOT="C:\Program Files\CollabNet Subversion Server\svnlook.exe"
set REPOS=%1%
set TXN=%2%

%SVNROOT% author %REPOS% -t %TXN% | findstr /r "^%VALID_USERS%$" >nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
   echo This is an invalid user 1>&2
   exit 1
) else (
   echo This is valid user 1>&2
   exit 0
)
```

The above pre-commit script failed as all users can commit their files. Also, the 'echo' command not working as I don't see any echo statement above. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you should want a pre-commit hook for that, so I give you a sketch what we are using when working on tags.

1. We use the Subversion [path-based authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz), and have rules like that:

   ```
   [/tags]
   * = r
   @R_SVN_ADMINS = rw
   ```

   so only admins are allowed to create and modify tags.
2. If necessary, we add for each tag a rule to avoid modification:

   ```
   [/tags/r1.0]
   @R_SVN_ADMINS = r
   ```
3. An alternative solution is to modify the rules in the first point after creation, so that tags are only read-only.

This works for us because tags are created seldomly, and we don't have much of them. We don't need any hooks to forbid something ...

Comment: Thanks mliebelt for your response. I thought of using pre-commit hook to restrict user from deleting file/folder in the /trunk directory.

Comment: Then you should rephrase your question (and perhaps title) to tell the people about your problem ...

Comment: @mliebelt, does the above authorization works for LDAP based authentication as well? I mean, users in the LDAP can access the repos but not able to set read,write permissions for all. I am not able to use "limit" because there are no groups created in LDAP. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Found the following solution working:

```
REM     Block deletion of folder/file in trunk
%SVNLOOK% changed %REPOS% -t %TXN% | findstr /r "^D.*trunk/.*$" >nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (goto DeleteInTrunkError)

REM     DeleteInTrunkError
REM ------------------------
:DeleteTrunkTagsError
echo. 1>&2
echo Trunk Delete Error: 1>&2
echo     Only Administrator can delete in the trunk folder. 1>&2
echo Commit details: 1>&2
%SVNROOT% changed %REPOS% -t %TXN% 1>&2
exit 1
```