# Change a Subversion file so it can never be modified

Tags: svn

Is it possible to change a file stored in Subversion so that it can never be modified? We have a file that we need to be stored in the system but no user should be able to update it.

Comment: Can't you just lock this file ?

Comment: I believe locks can be broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a pre-commit hook that rejects any commit which includes that file.

See [Implementing Repository Hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html).

Answer (score 2):

I see you've already accepted an answer, but I have a [Perl pre-commit hook](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/433257/newest_svn_hooks.zip) that does what you want. All you have to do is sent an entry in the control file:

```
[file You are not allowed to modify this file]
file = /the/file/you/cannot/modify.txt
access = read-only
users = @ALL
```

By the way, you should create an administrator's group that can modify these files, so you don't have to change the hook if you do have to modify it:

```
; Creates a group of users who are allowed to modify read-only files
[group admins]
users = firedragon, bob, ted, carol, alice

[file Only Admins are allowed to modify this file]
file = /the/file/you/cannot/modify.txt
access = read-only
users = @ALL

; Order is important. The last entry that matches
; the file is the one implemented
[file Only Admins are allowed to modify this file]
file = /the/file/you/cannot/modify.txt
access = read-write
users = @admins
```

You can specify a group of files using Ant-styled globs or Perl regular expressions, and the access control can be `read-write`, `read-only`, `no-delete`, or `add-only` which is great for tags. Users can create a tag, but not modify it.

```
[file You can create a tag, but not modify it]
file = /tags/**
access = read-only
users = @ALL

[file You can create a tag, but not modify it]
file = /tags/*/
access = add-only
users = @ALL
```

The first one removes all ability to write anywhere in the entire tags directory tree. The second one allows users to only add a tag directly under the `/tags/` directory.

By the way, you should create an administrator's group that can modify these files, so you don't have to change the hook if you do:

Comment: Fantastic comment. I have marked you up, wish I could do more :-/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `svn lock`, but other users can force the lock away. The best method is to use a hook that will deny modification of the file.

These articles should get you going:

- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.ref.svn.c.lock.html
- http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook
- [SVN pre-commit hook for avoiding changes to tags subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464384/svn-pre-commit-hook-for-avoiding-changes-to-tags-subdirectories)

Comment: Thanks for the information. It seems this is the way to go. I have given you a +1 but James gave the same answer first so have accepted his.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is yes and no both. Yes in the sense that you can `lock` the file and never `unlock` for other users. No in the sense that if you `unlock` the file, another user can `modify` it. Its up to you to find the right choice of answer.