# How to control changes to tags in SVN server on Windows

Tags: svn, tags, access-control, visualsvn-server

We use VisualSVN Server 2.5.6 on **Windows** (important!).

Most of our SVN repositories have the standard structure:

```
/trunk
/branches
/tags
```

**We want:**

- allow people to create new tags
- forbid them to modify existing tags

Don't ask... sometimes they really try to Commit a change to existing tag ))

I found a really nice pre-commit hook - **svnperms.py**
from standard [hook scripts](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/)

Example 2 from the configuration file is probably what I need:

```
[example2]
trunk/.* = *(add,remove,update)
tags/[^/]+/ = *(add)
branches/[^/]+/.* = *(add,remove,update)
```

Really powerful and concise!

But it doesn't work properly on Windows - fails with error message:

```
D:\Repositories\Ivan_dev\hooks>svnperms.py -r D:\Repositories\Ivan_dev -s default_permissions_configuration -R 8
svnlook author D:\Repositories\Ivan_dev -r 8
'{' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.error: command failed: svnlook author D:\Repositories\Ivan_dev -r 8
'{' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

As far as I understood it fails because of the way it's designed in Python:

> The commands module, which svnperms.py uses to run underlying svnlook
>   commands, only works on Unix.

from here: http://subversion.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=462&dsMessageId=72052

I really like the approach of svnperms.py to allow you controlling **add**, **remove** and **modify** actions (in line with A, D and M types of changes in SVN) instead of just **Read** and **Write** in authz module.

Plus it gives unlimited power because of regular expressions used to specify path.

Are there similar SVN hooks scripts that work on Windows?

I don't know Python unfortunately, but quite experienced in Perl. So even thinking about rewriting svnperms.py into Perl... but this will take a few hours, plus testing...

Comment: Why don't you set NO ACCESS rule to "/tags" in each repository?

Comment: There are a bunch of example Windows scripts for this scenario here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464384/svn-pre-commit-hook-for-avoiding-changes-to-tags-subdirectories

Comment: bahrep, I DO want people to create tags...

Comment: Mand, thanks for the good link! I see lots of interesting stuff there, will try some...