# How to remove a tag from tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I am unable to remove a wrongly created tag from my tags folder. I have tried switching my working copy to /tags and then simply removing the desired folder in the tags directory. But this makes the icon of the svn folder red and when I try to commit the changes I make, it won't let me.

So in short how can I delete a folder from /tags such that when others checkout to that path, they won't see them anymore?

Comment: "it won't let me" - that ought to work. What's the error? I don't know Tortoise well, but if you have a command-line client you can just do `svn rm <full URL to tag>`

Comment: It says: Commit failed, Commit blocked by pre-commit hook(exit code 1), with output:
you don't have enough permissions for this transaction.

I thought that this is because commits on tags is not allowed.

Comment: Right: that means that whoever set up your server has written a script to block that. You should talk to them. (Or try the command-line operation if you can: that might not trigger the hook, but I'm not 100% sure about that.)

Comment: @Rup also the command line operation will trigger the hook.

Comment: @Davide OK, thanks - I thought it might bypass it for some classes of removes, but I'm not surprised it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your description, the post-commit hook will need to be temporarily renamed.  Once you have completed your deletion, the hook can be renamed back to its original name.

Comment: This is correct. Kudos to your admin for setting this up, tags are meant to be immutable. There are a lot of ways to setup that hook, but likely it's using svnperms or some such sauce - you should look into making a service account that successfully falls through that hook so you can do the this kind of maintenance in the future.  That way you won't have to muck with the scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion by @BradBruce will certainly work but after I saw this question I searched around for a better way and found it at this SO question: [SVN pre-commit hook for avoiding changes to tags subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464384/svn-pre-commit-hook-for-avoiding-changes-to-tags-subdirectories), particularly useful because you are on Windows. The user @mcdon provides [a hook script that makes tags immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3550191/115690), as your admin seems to have done, but also provides a hook (pardon the overload there) that lets you allow one designated user to ignore the safeties--just what you are asking for! (You will see at the top of the script that you just have to set the Administrator variable to the user you wish to designate.)

Comment: Neat, although we only know that his client is Windows not necessarily his server.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're getting:

```
Commit failed, Commit blocked by pre-commit hook(exit code 1), 
with output: you don't have enough permissions for this transaction.
```

The key phrase is _blocked by [pre-commit hook](http://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook). This is preventing you from deleting the tag. In order to delete the tag, you'll have to find the administrator, and have them delete the tag, or give you permission to delete the tag.